# How to set a max character length for a button with CSS without making the content added with ::after selector disappear?

Tags: css

I have a scenario, where I have some buttons and I added 
font-awesome dropdown icons to them with the `::after` selector. However, the text of the buttons is often too long, therefore, I set their `max-width` property in characters - but this makes the dropdown icon disappear, if the text is too long.

I quickly created a plunker for the problem (the font awesome dropdown icon doesn't render, but it's not important for the question): [plnkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/sHxkMbuuO5Hau2OSRsO9?p=preview)

I would need the following:

Hello Plunke... *dropdown icon*

Comment: You’ll need to insert another element to wrap the text, so that you can limit the width of _that_, and leave the pseudo element alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the `:after` element to the right side.

```css
button {
    height: 21px;
    max-width: 13ch;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
button::after {
    content: "\f0dc";
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button>Hello Plunker!</button>
```